# oracle sqlplus wrapping results

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

When I run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM CAR;
```

the results appear but each row wraps to several lines.

How can I stop this wrapping so that each row appears on a single line?

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, even after changing `set lines` to a big number:

```
select * from dba_directories;

OWNER                          DIRECTORY_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
DIRECTORY_PATH
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYS                            DPUMP_DIR
C:\xxx

SYS                            CLEAN_PUMP_DIR
D:\yyy

SYS                            TCMCLEAN_DPUMP_DIR
C:\zzz
```

The way to do it was to use also: `set wrap off`

```
OWNER                          DIRECTORY_NAME                 DIRECTORY_PATH
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
SYS                            DPUMP_DIR                      C:\xxx
SYS                            CLEAN_PUMP_DIR                 D:\yyy
SYS                            TCMCLEAN_DPUMP_DIR             C:\zzz
```

Answer (score 3):

Really hard to tell quite what the question actually is; but if you're seeing each row of data wrapped onto multiple lines in SQL*Plus, you need to do `set lines 180` or similar; the number you use would ideally be the width of your terminal. The default is 80. You can go wider than the terminal, and it will still wrap, but you may find it easier to read still.

The documentation for all the `set` commands is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#sthref1904).

Comment: Thank heavens. This was driving me nuts, as a postgres user thrown into an Oracle environment and handed only gqlplus!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about SQLplus? If so try setting the column format. This webpage gives an example:
http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/beautify.html

Comment: so from this code what do you think i need to change in order to make the rows into 1 line 
CREATE TABLE CANDIDATE (
CANDIDATE_ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
POSITION_TYPE  VARCHAR (20),
POSTCODE VARCHAR(10),
TELEPHONE NUMBER);

Comment: @john: it's nothing to do with the table creation command, it's how the client - presumably SQL*Plus - formats the output when you query from the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably to do with the wrap of the text. I have completed this with my tables and it works:

SQL> set wrap off;