# Oracle XE query result wraps and looks clumsy in SQL command line

Tags: oracle-xe

Im using oracle XE on windows7. In SQL command line, the query results were wrapped, each row has table header wraped for each row and the console looks horrible to read through results. 
    Let me know the command to indent(set right) the results columns on single line and each row one by one.

```
"
TABLE_NAME                     TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------ ------------------------------
CLUSTER_NAME                   IOT_NAME                       STATUS
------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------
  PCT_FREE   PCT_USED  INI_TRANS  MAX_TRANS INITIAL_EXTENT NEXT_EXTENT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- -----------
MIN_EXTENTS MAX_EXTENTS PCT_INCREASE  FREELISTS FREELIST_GROUPS LOG B   NUM_ROWS
----------- ----------- ------------ ---------- --------------- --- - ----------
    BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS  AVG_SPACE  CHAIN_CNT AVG_ROW_LEN
---------- ------------ ---------- ---------- -----------
AVG_SPACE_FREELIST_BLOCKS NUM_FREELIST_BLOCKS
------------------------- -------------------
DEGREE
----------------------------------------
INSTANCES                                CACHE                TABLE_LO
---------------------------------------- -------------------- --------
SAMPLE_SIZE LAST_ANAL PAR IOT_TYPE     T S NES BUFFER_ FLASH_C CELL_FL ROW_MOVE
----------- --------- --- ------------ - - --- ------- ------- ------- --------
GLO USE DURATION        SKIP_COR MON CLUSTER_OWNER                  DEPENDEN
--- --- --------------- -------- --- ------------------------------ --------
COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR DRO REA SEG RESULT_...."
```

Comment: Are you talking about SQL*Plus? If so [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10499673/266304); and this is probably a duplicate of that question. (Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3006431/266304), but that's lost its image; or many others).

Comment: possible duplicate of [oracle sqlplus wrapping results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499544/oracle-sqlplus-wrapping-results)

Comment: So did you try something like `set linesize 1024` as suggested in the linked questions? You can also `set wrap off` but that will truncate the output. You're always going to have a lot of output with `select * from user_tables` though; selecting only the columns you need will make life easier, but you'll still need to change the linesize sometimes.